# How to add a custom event to datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to make a column editable by default in a datatable.

I do not want to use rowEditor. As I do not want a coloumn to become editable on click of any button.

I am able to make a cell editable by default. But, as per my understanding, cell editor does not have any event associated with it.

How can I add an event to the cell.

The code through which I made the cell editable is:

```
<p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputLabel value="Field 1" />
                    </f:facet>

                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{emp.empCode}" />
                        </f:facet>

                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <p:inputText value="#{emp.empCode}" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
```

Thanks,
Shikha

Comment: What kind of event are you talking about? I am pretty sure you can use the events available in the p:inputText... Have you tried that?

Comment: Why not using input fields for all cells instead of outputText?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I do not want to use rowEditor. As I do not want a coloumn to become editable on click of any button.*

Just replace

```
<p:cellEditor>
    <f:facet name="input">
        <h:outputLabel value="#{emp.empCode}" />
    </f:facet>

    <f:facet name="output">
        <p:inputText value="#{emp.empCode}" />
    </f:facet>
</p:cellEditor>
```

by

```
<p:inputText value="#{emp.empCode}" />
```

and remove `<p:rowEditor>`. Add if necessary a save button below the table.